# Wrong python architecture found when running TensorFlow in R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, architecture, rstudio

I am using RStudio Version 1.1.456 in Anaconda 3 64 Bit and try to run TensorFlow in R.
I am running python version 3.6.10 in my conda environment.

Installing tensorflow using

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(envname = 'rstudio')
```

finished succesfully.

`test <- tf$constant("Hello TensorFlow")` produced the error: Error: Your current architecture is 64bit; however, this version of Python was compiled for 32bit.

As far as I could find out Anaconda installed the 64BIT python environment

At the moment I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the small 'miniconda' Python distribution. You can use the `install_miniconda()` function from the `reticulate package` to accomplish this. This solved the problem for me.